# Connection keycloak with MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, keycloak

I was try to doing different connections with keycloak and MySQL, and always i get the next error:

`Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("subsystem" => "microprofile-metrics-smallrye")]): java.lang.NullPointerException`

I read differents articles about this problem but anyone don't give me a concrete answer, I try with mariadb and the problem is the same and once i used the integrate gui that have keycloack on the url: http://127.0.0.1:9990/ but nothing changed, the connection take some minutes and create some of tables but finished with the last error

Comment: I can't publish my connection is too long

Answer (score 0):

In this post https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/wildfly-nullpointerexception/747, the user says that each time keycloak is deployed, it generates a new random password for the database.

Therefore, while the database password remained the same, keycloak always tried to use its own newly generated password to connect to the DB.

That person's solution was to set the DB password explicitly in the keycloak config file (values.yml).